# Работа со свойствами C#

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, getter, setter

Начинаю осваивать парадигму ООП при помощи языка C# и в одном из заданий столкнулся с вопросом на который с листа не могу найти ответа.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, насколько корректно работать со свойствами подобным образом:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Testing
{ 
   class Properties:INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public long Clock
        {
            get { return Clock; }
            set {
                Clock = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("XXX"));
                }
        }
        public void WorkingCycle()
        { Clock++; }

   }
}
```

Насколько корректно в аксессорах получать значение самого свойства и самому же свойству присваивать значение. С одной стороны, по скольку код связан с WinForms работа в таком виде кажется удобной.
Или всё же стоит объявить поле и работать в аксессорах с ним?

Comment: _Насколько корректно в аксессорах получать значение самого свойства_ - насоколько корректно в начале метода вызывать самого себя? Бесконечная рекурсия, `StackOverflowException`. Вы бы сначала код проверили, работает ли, прежде чем вопрос задавать. Он не работает.

Comment: Ок. Возьму на заметку. Спасибо!

Comment: Хотите в коде чистоту, используйте генераторы кода, будет у вас тогда просто `[ObservableProperty] private long clock;`, а "где-то", за вас автоматически создадут все то, что в вопросе (с приватным полем),. Правда не советую без знаний того, как работает INPC) Ну а код из вопроса... 1. INPC интерфейс обычно выносят в отдельный класс, чтоб не писать везде событие и его реализацию. 2. Как и сказали выше, вы получите ошибку, ибо зациклили код. Приватное поле не просто так ведь делают, ибо оно хранит в себе данные свойства.

Comment: Спасибо большое!